# Pandas merge on non-unique columns gives different results

Tags: python, pandas

I am having two dataframes that I would like to join:

The first one (**products**) looks like this:

```
category,deleted,availability,approval,quality_issue,expiring,merchant_id,date,product_id
alimentation & boissons,-2.0,in stock,0,0.0,0.0,11061,08/30/2017,7997
alimentation & boissons,-2.0,in stock,approved,-2.0,0.0,11061,08/30/2017,65
alimentation & boissons,1.0,in stock,0,0.0,0.0,11061,08/30/2017,2186
```

Then I have one more (**accounts**) that looks like this:

```
merchant_id, status
11060, 0
11061, Not performing automatic item updates for availability
```

Ideally, what I would like to have at the end is one dataframe with all the values together (adding the status as a column at the end):

```
category,deleted,availability,approval,quality_issue,expiring,merchant_id,date,product_id, status
    alimentation & boissons,-2.0,in stock,0,0.0,0.0,11061,08/30/2017,7997, Not performing automatic item updates for availability
    alimentation & boissons,-2.0,in stock,approved,-2.0,0.0,11061,08/30/2017,65, Not performing automatic item updates for availability
    alimentation & boissons,1.0,in stock,0,0.0,0.0,11061,08/30/2017,2186, Not performing automatic item updates for availability
```

I am using this merge type:

```
merged = pd.merge(account_statuses_agg,
                  account_statuses_df,
                         left_on='merchant_id',
                         right_on='merchant_id',
                         how='outer'
                         ).replace(np.nan, 0)
```

However what I am getting as result is:

```
category,deleted,availability,approval,quality_issue,expiring,merchant_id,date,product_id, status
    alimentation & boissons,-2.0,in stock,0,0.0,0.0,11061,08/30/2017,7997, 0
    alimentation & boissons,-2.0,in stock,approved,-2.0,0.0,11061,08/30/2017,65, 0
    alimentation & boissons,1.0,in stock,0,0.0,0.0,11061,08/30/2017,2186, 0
0 ,0 , 0 ,0 ,0 ,0 11061, 0 ,0 ,  Not performing automatic item updates for availability
```

Is that something on the way merge is happening? Should every value be unique in order to merge/join in pandas?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Might be a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21573137/how-to-extract-values-of-one-dataframe-with-values-of-other-dataframe-in-pandas

Comment: Instead of doing an `outer` join, try to do a `left` or `inner` join.
Here you can find a visual explanation of what the different join types are:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins