# How do I compare the two data frames and get the values?

Tags: python, dataframe

[image: x dataframe]
[image: y dataframe]

The x data frame is information about departure and arrival, and the y data frame is latitude and longitude data for each location.

I try to calculate the distance between the origin and destination using the latitude and longitude data of start and end (e.g., start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y).

How can I connect x and y to bring the latitude data that fits each code into the x data frame?

Comment: Do you want like new columns in the first dataframe with your start and end or you only care about the resulting distance ?

Comment: Both.
But I am thinking of applying the harbour sine formula inside Python and first, I want to add the column start_x, start_y, end_x, and end_y inside the x data frame.

Comment: I can't do any testing just now but I would try something like : x["start_x"] = y.loc[y.code == x.start].x and so forth for the next ones ..

Comment: It might not work but it's a start :p I wish I was in front of my computer !

Comment: x["start_x"] = y.loc[y['code'] == x['start']] I wrote like this, and I got an error like ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Comment: Try with list comprehension then. x["start_x"] = [y.loc[y['code'] == i].x for i in x.start]

Comment: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'x'                                              
What does .x mean? I've never seen a code like that before.

Comment: x["start_x"] = [y.loc[y['code'] == i][x] for i['start']]
I did this and it's working now. I think the results will come out soon.

Comment: It would be to get your x column. Same thing as y["x"] ! Because the columns are attributes of the dataframe

Comment: Thank you very much. The results aren't out yet. I think it will take a long time because there is a lot of data.

Comment: The start_x column contains only "Empty DataFrame Columns: [code] Index: []". It's tens of thousands.

Comment: Ha my bad there was an error in the list comprehension ! Try : x["start_x"] = [y.loc[y['code'] == i]["x"] for i in x['start']] and the code could be written like : x["start_x"] = [y.loc[y.code == i].x for i in x.start] it is a bit clearer like that.

Comment: Take a look at this question : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21573137/how-to-extract-values-of-one-dataframe-with-values-of-other-dataframe-in-pandas)

Comment: I keep trying, but it isn't resolved.

Comment: I have replicated your situation and have been able to make it work, might not be the best solution but I will post it in the answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

The notation is somewhat confusing, but I took it after the question's notation.

One way to do would be by merging your dataframes into a new one like so :

#### Dummy dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd

x=[300,500,300,600,700]
y=[400,400,700,700,400]

code=[300,400,500,600,700]

start=[100,101,102,103,104]

end=[110,111,112,113,114]

x={"x":x, "y":y}

y={"code":code, "start":start, "end":end}

x=pd.DataFrame(x)

y=pd.DataFrame(y)
```

This gives:

```
x
```

|  | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 300 | 400 |
| 1 | 500 | 400 |
| 2 | 300 | 700 |
| 3 | 600 | 700 |
| 4 | 700 | 400 |

```
y
```

|  | code | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 300 | 100 | 110 |
| 1 | 400 | 101 | 111 |
| 2 | 500 | 102 | 112 |
| 3 | 600 | 103 | 113 |
| 4 | 700 | 104 | 114 |

#### Solution :

```
df = pd.merge(x,y,left_on="x",right_on="code").drop("code",axis=1)

df
```

|  | x | y | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 300 | 400 | 100 | 110 |
| 1 | 300 | 700 | 100 | 110 |
| 2 | 500 | 400 | 102 | 112 |
| 3 | 600 | 700 | 103 | 113 |
| 4 | 700 | 400 | 104 | 114 |

```
df = df.merge(y,left_on="y",right_on="code").drop("code",axis=1)

df
```

|  | x | y | start_x | end_x | start_y | end_y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 300 | 400 | 100 | 110 | 101 | 111 |
| 1 | 500 | 400 | 102 | 112 | 101 | 111 |
| 2 | 700 | 400 | 104 | 114 | 101 | 111 |
| 3 | 300 | 700 | 100 | 110 | 104 | 114 |
| 4 | 600 | 700 | 103 | 113 | 104 | 114 |

#### Quick explanation :

The line df = pd.merge(...) creates the new dataframe by merging the left one (x) on the "x" column and the right one on the "code" column. The second line df = df.merge(...) takes the existing df as the left one, and uses its column "y" to merge the "code" column from the y dataframe.

The .drop("code",axis=1) is used to drop the unwanted "code" column resulting from the merging.

The _x and _y suffixes are added automatically when merging dataframes that have the same column names. To control it, use the "suffixe=.." option when calling the second merging (when the column with the same name are merging). In this case it works right with the default setting so no bothering with this if you use the x as right and y as left dataframes.

Comment: I will try. I think it will work. Thank you very much.